# Can't navigate/select in ListView with dPad (or remote controller)

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a cross project with Xamarin,
and on Android or Android TV I can't select an item in a listview 
with my remote controller or dPad (touchscreen all work fine).

```
<ListView x:Name="CategoriesListView" HasUnevenRows="True"
        ItemsSource="{ Binding Categories }">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Center"  >
                        <Label x:Name="CategoryItem" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Small" 
                        Text="{Binding CategoryName}"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Review the "Create TV navigation" section" : https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/controllers

Comment: Thanks for your answer @SushiHangover I readed but I don't understand -_- , what must I do for my xamarin app.

Comment: @AliDm  Have solved it? Can you share the code?